# Is it ever possible for the getPath method of a java.net.URI object to return null? (If so, when?)

Tags: java, null, uri

According to the [URI javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getPath%28%29) the `getPath` method returns "the decoded path component of this URI, **or null if the path is undefined**" (emphasis added). This would lead me to believe that if my application relies on the return value of `getPath`, I might need to check if it is `null`. However, it seems that this can never happen.

The following code shows my attempts to construct a `URI` object for which `getPath` returns null, but as you can see, I have not yet found such a case. Could someone please explain how this might happen?

**EDIT: It has come to my attention that a `mailto` URI does not have a path.** However, what I am really asking is: Can there be a URI that uses http, https, ftp, or file scheme that has an undefined/null path?

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class URIGetPathNullTest {

    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
        test1();
        test2();
        test3();
        test4();
        test5();
        test6();
        test7();
    }


    public static void test1() throws URISyntaxException {
        String urlString = "";
        URI uri = new URI(urlString);
        printUri(uri); 
        // Output:
        //  toString() --> 
        //  getPath --> 
        //  getPath null? false         
    }

    public static void test2() throws URISyntaxException{
        String scheme = null;
        String ssp = null;
        String fragment = null;
        URI uri = new URI(
                scheme,
                ssp,
                fragment
            );
        printUri(uri);       
        // Output:
        //  toString() --> 
        //  getPath --> 
        //  getPath null? false
    }

    public static void test3() throws URISyntaxException {
        String scheme = null;
        String userInfo = null;
        String host = null;
        int port = -1;
        String path = null;
        String query = null;
        String fragment = null;
        URI uri = new URI(
                scheme,
                userInfo,
                host,
                port,
                path,
                query,
                fragment             
            );
        printUri(uri);       
        // Output:
        //  toString() --> 
        //  getPath --> 
        //  getPath null? false

    }

    public static void test4() throws URISyntaxException {
        String scheme = null;
        String host = null;
        String path = null;
        String fragment = null;
        URI uri = new URI(
                scheme,
                host,
                path,
                fragment             
            );
        printUri(uri);       
        // Output:
        //  toString() --> 
        //  getPath --> 
        //  getPath null? false
    }

    public static void test5() throws URISyntaxException {
        String scheme = null;
        String authority = null;
        String path = null;
        String query = null;
        String fragment = null;
        URI uri = new URI(
                scheme,
                authority,
                path,
                query,
                fragment             
            );
        printUri(uri);       
        // Output:
        //  toString() --> 
        //  getPath --> 
        //  getPath null? false
    }

    public static void test6() throws URISyntaxException {
        String urlString = "?some-query";
        URI uri = new URI(urlString);
        printUri(uri); 
        // Output:
        //  toString() --> ?some-query
        //  getPath --> 
        //  getPath null? false         
    }

    public static void test7() throws URISyntaxException {
        String urlString = "#some-fragment";
        URI uri = new URI(urlString);
        printUri(uri); 
        // Output:
        //  toString() --> #some-fragment
        //  getPath --> 
        //  getPath null? false         
    }

    public static void printUri(URI uri) {
        System.out.println("toString() --> " + uri.toString());
        System.out.println("getPath --> " + uri.getPath());
        System.out.println("getPath null? " + (uri.getPath() == null));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was reading over [RFC2956](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) and noticed that I was only thinking of URIs corresponding to http/ftp/file schemes. A `mailto` URI is an example of one that does not have a path.

```
public static void test8() throws URISyntaxException {
    String urlString = "mailto:mduerst@ifi.unizh.ch";
    URI uri = new URI(urlString);
    printUri(uri); 
    // Output:
    //  toString() --> mailto:mduerst@ifi.unizh.ch
    //  getPath --> null
    //  getPath null? true          
}
```

**EDIT**: Likewise with the `news` scheme.

```
public static void test9() throws URISyntaxException {
    String urlString = "news:comp.infosystems.www.servers.unix";
    URI uri = new URI(urlString);
    printUri(uri); 
    // Output:
    //  toString() --> news:comp.infosystems.www.servers.unix
    //  getPath --> null
    //  getPath null? true          
}
```

---

**(I've combined my other answer below)**

There's a good clue at [the beginning of the URI javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html):

> An opaque URI is an absolute URI whose scheme-specific part does not begin with a slash
>   character ('/'). Opaque URIs are not subject to further parsing. Some examples of opaque
>   URIs are:
>
> mailto:java-net@java.sun.com
>   news:comp.lang.java
>   urn:isbn:096139210x

It seems that `getPath` returns null if and only if the `URI` is opaque, which is easy to check with the [`isOpaque` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#isOpaque()). So if I ensure that the URI is not opaque then I should not need to check the result of `getPath` for `null`.

Looking at the [source for java.net.URI](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/net/URI.java#URI) in openjdk 7-b147, I noticed a comment by the `path` field then looked at the source for `isOpaque`, which seems to confirm this:

```
private transient String path;  // null ==> opaque

// ...

public boolean isOpaque() {
    return path == null;
}
```